# How to get monthly reports from multiple records?

Tags: sql, laravel, database, model, controller

I have a table name ‘attlog’ that contain multiple records from machine scan. Each person have more than one record depend on their scan.

I would like to get monthly reports person from that table with time scan in and out.

[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqFYP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of SQL you are using.  I am going to use SQL Fiddle set to SQL Server.

First, create table and data for key elements.

```
-- create table
create table attlog
(
  employee_id varchar(10),
  scan_date datetime,
  employee_direction varchar(10)
);

-- add sample data
insert into attlog values ('0001', '2023-03-02 08:00:00', 'in');
insert into attlog values ('0002', '2023-03-02 09:00:00', 'in');
insert into attlog values ('0001', '2023-03-02 12:00:00', 'out');
insert into attlog values ('0001', '2023-03-02 13:00:00', 'in');
insert into attlog values ('0002', '2023-03-02 17:00:00', 'out');
insert into attlog values ('0001', '2023-03-02 17:30:00', 'out');
```

In the above example, employee 2 stays at his desk for lunch.  Employee 1 goes out for lunch.

You can use lead or lag functions to group times in and times out.

```
-- group trips together
select 
  d.employee_id,
  d.scan_date as curr_date,
  d.employee_direction as curr_direction,
  d.next_scan,
  d.next_direction
from
(
  select 
    *,
    LEAD(scan_date, 1, '1900-01-01') OVER (ORDER BY employee_id, scan_date) AS next_scan, 
    LEAD(employee_direction, 1, 'unknown') OVER (ORDER BY employee_id, scan_date) AS next_direction
  from attlog
) as d
where d.employee_direction = 'in'
```

This assumes that every in trip has an out trip.  If you have data integrity issues, you can modify this query to find them.

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/847411/17/0